# How can I add more than one handleClick with checkbox using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use this function to replace `selection` with `text`.
When choosing the `option` "***I can't find my city***" or "***I can't find my college***".

It worked when applied to one, but when I added another function,
it only worked with the other. I need to add an ID or something like that, but I can't figure out the correct way.

```js
function handleClick(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    console.log(checkbox.value + "True");
    citysel.style.display = "none";
    citytex.style.display = "block";

  } else {
    console.log(checkbox.value + "False")
    citysel.style.display = "block";
    citytex.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function handleClick(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    console.log(checkbox.value + "True");
    collgesel.style.display = "none";
    collge.style.display = "block";

  } else {
    console.log(checkbox.value + "False")
    collgesel.style.display = "block";
    collge.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<label> In any city you living? </label>

<div id="citytex">
  <input type="text" placeholder="city name"> /*display:none;*/
</div>

<div id="citysel">
  <div class="select">
    <select name="city">
      <option value="" disabled selected>city</option>
      <option value="">city1</option>
      <option value="">city2</option>
      <option value="">city3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<span>
<div class="check"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="unfoundcity" onclick='handleClick(this);' value="unfound">
Can't find your city?
</div>
</span>

<label> College Name? </label>
<div id="collgesel">
  <div class="select">
    <select name="collge">
      <option value="" disabled selected>The college you graduated from</option>
      <option value="">college1</option>
      <option value="">college2</option>
      <option value="">college3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="collge" placeholder="college name"> /*display:none;*/


<span>
  <div class="check"> 
<input type="checkbox"  onclick='handleClick(this);' name="collge" value="">
 can't find your college?
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Please revise the demo above so it accurately shows the problem.

Comment: The proper way is to pass an element to the function rather than hard-coding it in the function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you have two function of the same name, the second over writes the first. You must use unique names.

Comment: @Twisty yes but how the right way to do this? sorry but I'm really a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Consider just one function that can handle both scenarios.

```js
function handleClick(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.classList.contains("city")) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      console.log(checkbox.value + "True");
      citysel.style.display = "none";
      citytex.style.display = "block";

    } else {
      console.log(checkbox.value + "False");
      citysel.style.display = "block";
      citytex.style.display = "none";
    }
  } else {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      console.log(checkbox.value + "True");
      collgesel.style.display = "none";
      collge.style.display = "block";

    } else {
      console.log(checkbox.value + "False");
      collgesel.style.display = "block";
      collge.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label> In any city you living? </label>

<div id="citytex">
  <input type="text" placeholder="city name"> /*display:none;*/
</div>

<div id="citysel">
  <div class="select">
    <select name="city">
      <option value="" disabled selected>city</option>
      <option value="">city1</option>
      <option value="">city2</option>
      <option value="">city3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<span>
<div class="check"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="unfoundcity" onclick='handleClick(this);' value="unfound">
Can't find your city?
</div>
</span>

<label> College Name? </label>
<div id="collgesel">
  <div class="select">
    <select name="collge">
      <option value="" disabled selected>The college you graduated from</option>
      <option value="">college1</option>
      <option value="">college2</option>
      <option value="">college3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="collge" placeholder="college name"> /*display:none;*/


<span>
  <div class="check"> 
<input type="checkbox"  onclick='handleClick(this);' name="collge" value="">
 can't find your college?
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: thank you I used your js code, ,but Still the same problem, did you change anything in HTML?
Because I did not find any differences, Is there something that needs to be changed in html and I didn't notice it?